# Getting a 403 forbidden error when posting in Facebook using Prime31 pkugin from Unity3d

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, prime31

Before I ask my question here are a few details of my setup and the problem I am facing.
This is my first post on StackOverflow :).

Platform : 
Unity3d engine + Prime31 plugin for Facebook

Context : 
I am trying to integrate Facebook into our Mobile iOS app, developed using Unity3d (still in development), and I am trying to post to the user's friend's wall using a plugin called Prime31.

Problem :
I keep getting a 403 forbidden error when I post to the friends wall

Code :
I am using the following piece of code

```
var token = FacebookBinding.getAccessToken();
            Debug.Log( "access token: " + token );  

            var param = new Dictionary<string,object>
                {
                    {"message", "Test message for dragons "},
                    {"access_token" , token},
                    {"name", "School of Dragons"},
                    {"caption", "Join the world of Dragons"},
                };

            Facebook.instance.post(id+"/feed",param, OnPostComplete);
```

Where id is retrieved from another piece of code.

Additional Info :

1. With the same setup, publishing on my own wall works. (me/feed instead of id/feed)
2. The friend I am trying to post to and myself both are listed as developers in the account for the app.
3. I have the the info.plist additions according to the steps provided by Prime31.
4. I have done extensive googling on this problem and most of the replies indicate a high number of posts being made from the server / app as a possible reason.

Questions :

1. Is filling in the Native IOS App setting in the developer console a must for publishing ?
2. Is the number of posts made by a developer application in Facebook restricted ? Because I can post to the same friends wall with the same content outside of the app. This seems to be the least likely scenario.
3. Why could this problem be happening ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as we have a deadline approaching in three days and this feature should be done and ready in a couple of days.

Thanks
Anur

Answer (score 0):

When I use me/photo to share a picture I have meet 403 error.My case is because of my Facebook app not approve the publish_actions permission,and I use a normal user for test,just test user can use not approved permissions.You can use app manage page's menu "Status & Review" -> "Submission" to request permission.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm using unity3D I had the same FBResult::Error (res.Error.Text) text (403 forbidden)
You need to see what the res.ToString() says.

For example mine is

```
 ""message":"(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions","type":"OAuthException","code":200,"fbtrace_id":"C3X4jSCm7or"
```